# FormControlName doesn't get associated with parent FormGroup in recursive template

Tags: angular, recursion, angular-forms

I'm trying to implement a recursive template strategy for displaying an nth level of checkboxes in an unordered list. I have the formGroup being created through loops and all works fine, but the template is what's giving me issues. I've tried many different approaches I've found here on SO but each one results in the same error: `ERROR Error: formControlName must be used with a parent formGroup directive.  You'll want to add a formGroup`.

I feel as though I'm close but just missing something that ties it all together. Any insight is greatly appreciated.

HTML

```
<form *ngIf="permissionsForm" [formGroup]="permissionsForm">
  <ng-container 
    *ngTemplateOutlet="recursiveList; context: { $implicit: permissionFields, formGroup: permissionsForm }">
  </ng-container>
</form>

<ng-template #recursiveList let-permissionFields let-formGroup="formGroup">
  <div class="form-group">
    <ng-container *ngFor="let item of permissionFields">
      <ng-container *ngIf="item.childpermissions; else default;">
        <div [formGroup]="formGroup.get(item.name)">
          <ng-container
            *ngTemplateOutlet="recursiveList; context: { $implicit: item.childpermissions, formGroup: formGroup.get(item.name) }">
          </ng-container>
        </div>
      </ng-container>
      <ng-template #default>
        <div>
          <hhax-checkbox [formControlName]="formGroup.get(item.name)"></hhax-checkbox>
        </div>
      </ng-template>
    </ng-container>
  </div>
</ng-template>
```

Typescript

```
public permissionsForm: FormGroup = this.generatePermissionsForm();

generatePermissionsForm(): FormGroup {
    const baseForm = this.fb.group({});
    this.permissionFields.forEach(field => {
      baseForm.addControl(field.name, this.generateFormGroup(baseForm, field));
    });
    return baseForm;
  }

  generateFormGroup(baseForm: FormGroup, field): FormGroup | FormControl {
    if (field.childPermissions) {
      const formGroup = this.fb.group({});
      field.childPermissions.forEach(item => {
        formGroup.addControl(item.name, this.generateFormGroup(formGroup, item));
      });
      return formGroup;
    }

    return new FormControl('');
  }
```

**If more information is needed don't hesitate to comment**

Answer (score 0):

From what I gather, you'd like to iterate over a collection of permissions each with their own child permissions and then render all permissions with some checkboxes.
You can achieve something like this using form arrays.
I would do it in the following way:

permissions object:

```
interface permission {
  name: string;
  childPermissions: childPermission[];
}
interface childPermission {
  name: string;
}
  permissionFields: permission[] = [
    {
      name: 'permission 1',
      childPermissions: [
        { name: 'child permission 1.1' },
        { name: 'child permission 1.2' },
      ],
    },
    {
      name: 'permission 2',
      childPermissions: [
        { name: 'child permission 2.1' },
        { name: 'child permission 2.2' },
      ],
    },
    {
      name: 'permission 3',
      childPermissions: [
        { name: 'child permission 3.1' },
        { name: 'child permission 3.2' },
        { name: 'child permission 3.3' },
      ],
    },
    {
      name: 'permission 4',
      childPermissions: [
        { name: 'child permission 4.1' },
        { name: 'child permission 4.2' },
      ],
    },
  ];
```

typescript:

```
 permissionForm: any;
 private initForm() {
    this.permissionForm = this.fb.group({
      permissions: this.fb.array(this.getPermissionFormGroups()),
    });
  }

  private getPermissionFormGroups(): any[] {
    let permissions: any[] = [];
    this.permissionFields.forEach((permission) => {
      permissions.push(
        this.fb.group({
          permission: permission.name,
          checked: false,
          childPermissions: this.fb.array(
            this.getChildPermissionFormGroups(permission.childPermissions)
          ),
        })
      );
    });
    return permissions;
  }

  private getChildPermissionFormGroups(childPermissions: childPermission[]): any[] {
    let childrenPermissions: any[] = [];
    childPermissions.forEach((childPermission) => {
      childrenPermissions.push(
        this.fb.group({
          childPermission: childPermission.name,
          checked: false,
        })
      );
    });
    return childrenPermissions;
  }

  get permissionsFormArray() {
    return this.permissionForm?.get('permissions') as FormArray;
  }

  public childPermissionsFormArray(index: number) {
    return this.permissionsFormArray.controls[index].get(
      'childPermissions'
    ) as FormArray;
  }
```

HTML:

```
<div>
  <form [formGroup]="permissionForm">
    <div formArrayName="permissions">
      <div
        class="card w-50 m-2 p-2"
        *ngFor="let permission of permissionsFormArray.controls; let i = index"
        [formGroupName]="i"
      >
        <div class="d-flex justify-content-between">
          <mat-form-field>
            <mat-label>Permission</mat-label>
            <input matInput type="text" formControlName="permission" />
          </mat-form-field>
          <mat-checkbox matInput formControlName="checked"></mat-checkbox>
        </div>
        <div formArrayName="childPermissions">
          <div
            class="card m-3"
            *ngFor="
              let childPermission of childPermissionsFormArray(i).controls;
              let j = index
            "
            [formGroupName]="j"
          >
            <div class="d-flex justify-content-between">
              <mat-form-field>
                <mat-label>Child permission</mat-label>
                <input matInput type="text" formControlName="childPermission" />
              </mat-form-field>
              <mat-checkbox matInput formControlName="checked"></mat-checkbox>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

This will render a card for every permission, and inside that card, a card for every child permission.

I added a field called checked to the form groups to allow for you to keep track of what permissions are accepted or not.

If you select a few checkboxes and then run `console.log(JSON.stringify(this.permissionForm.value))`, you will be able to see the form in JSON format like this:

```
{
  "permissions": [
    {
      "permission": "permission 1",
      "checked": true,
      "childPermissions": [
        {
          "childPermission": "child permission 1.1",
          "checked": false
        },
        {
          "childPermission": "child permission 1.2",
          "checked": true
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "permission": "permission 2",
      "checked": true,
      "childPermissions": [
        {
          "childPermission": "child permission 2.1",
          "checked": true
        },
        {
          "childPermission": "child permission 2.2",
          "checked": false
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "permission": "permission 3",
      "checked": true,
      "childPermissions": [
        {
          "childPermission": "child permission 3.1",
          "checked": true
        },
        {
          "childPermission": "child permission 3.2",
          "checked": true
        },
        {
          "childPermission": "child permission 3.3",
          "checked": false
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "permission": "permission 4",
      "checked": false,
      "childPermissions": [
        {
          "childPermission": "child permission 4.1",
          "checked": false
        },
        {
          "childPermission": "child permission 4.2",
          "checked": false
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

If you plan on using angular material, don't forget to add any necessary imports:

```
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    FormsModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    MatFormFieldModule,
    MatInputModule,
    MatCheckboxModule
  ],
```